# Colors disappear after drawing image

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to draw a sphere and a cube at the same time on my screen. But the colors of my cube(which gets drawn first) dissapear. I don't understand why.

the sphere on the right is fine. But my cube  on the left isn't.
I added texture to both:

[image: visualization]

I can perfectly draw both of them seperately, but when I try to draw both of them on one widget something goes wrong.
I tought the popping and pushing would solve this issue, but it doesn't.

code:

```
void MyGLWidget::drawCube()
{

    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(position,0.5,-0.1,-0.5,-0.5,0,0,0,1);

    glTranslatef( 0.5, 0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(getCubeAngle(), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

    glPushMatrix();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       //back
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-0.1, 0.1,-0.1 );
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1,-0.1); 
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(0.1,-0.1,-0.1); 
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-0.1,-0.1,-0.1);
    /*rest of cube gets drawn*/
      glEnd();
     glFlush();
     glPopMatrix();
}

void MyGLWidget::drawSun()
{
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturePlanet[0]);

   glPushMatrix();
   glScalef(1,1,1);
   glLoadIdentity();
   GLUquadricObj *quadric=gluNewQuadric();
   gluQuadricTexture(quadric, GLU_TRUE);
   gluQuadricNormals(quadric, GLU_SMOOTH);

   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texturePlanet[0]);//

   gluSphere(quadric, 0.25, 360,360);
   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);//

   gluDeleteQuadric(quadric);
  glPopMatrix();

}

void MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    drawCube();
    drawSun();
}
```

Comment: shouldn't there be a `glEnd()` when you are finished drawing your cube?

Comment: I forgot to copy thaat part. here u go

Comment: I recommend to not clear the depth and color buffer inside the drawCube method because once you change the order it won't work anymore.
Note that `glBegin(...) ... glEnd(...)` is **deprecated** for learning it's perfectly fine but for some RealWorldApplications you want to consider Vertex Buffer Object.
Also ALL Matrix operations `glTranslatef() glPushMatrix() glPopMatrix() ...` are deprecated. In newer OpenGL versions you are asked to do all Matrix multiplication on your own.

Answer (score 0):

It is because In your cube drawing, you didn't enable texturing.

```
 glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //ADD THIS TO ENABLE TEXTURING
 glPushMatrix();
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       //back
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-0.1, 0.1,-0.1 );
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1,-0.1); 
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(0.1,-0.1,-0.1); 
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-0.1,-0.1,-0.1);
    /*rest of cube gets drawn*/
 glEnd();
 glFlush();
 glPopMatrix();

 glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // ADD THIS TO DISABLE TEXTURING
```